# Android studio - Unable to move Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

Am trying to install Android Studio for first time. When I try to launch the application the setup wizard tries to download some components but then throws the following error:

```
Connecting to 'http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip'...
Downloading 'android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip' from 'http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip'...
Unpacking android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
Unable to move Android SDK
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried starting the Downloader (or Android Studio) as Administrator? I stumbled upon that problem quite often when using Windows---on Mac OS it just works.

Comment: I did quickly try that before submitting the post just in case and just tried it again and has the same issue. The only possible thing I can think of is I changed the install location but shouldn't think that would cause a problem.

Comment: ++1 I am getting the same error to. Just google'd for it and reached your question.

Comment: The origin of this error: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/f0d863d1b6ae48f61baa2c0332a6354fc5253494/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/welcome/InstallComponentsPath.java

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu Running as admin worked for me. Please, post your comment as an answer to have my upvote. Hopefully it will also work for HuwD and your answer might get to be accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using Android Studio on Windows-based computers, I often stumbled upon this particular problem. Running Android Studio as admin (context-click on the application icon > Run as administrator) fixed the problem on every occurrence I’ve had so far.

My guess is that Android Studio doesn’t have write-rights to the path that is used and therefore needs the extended rights.
On Linux and Mac OS, however, I have not yet had similar problems using Android Studio.

Comment: Have reinstalled the application in it's default location and it runs fine. Guess for some reason it didn't like where I was trying to put it.

Comment: I actually *did* run this "as administrator" but changed the default location of the SDK from c:\users\me\AppData\wherever to n:\Android\sdk.  It shouldn't be a rights issue but it is because the first program ran as administrator but this then spawned a second program to download the SDK zip and it's this one then that didn't have the correct rights.  I manually downloaded https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip to my hardrive, unzipped it and then cut/pasted the resulting android-sdk-windows folder to my N: drive.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me to advance a little bit more (but now failing at installing Intel® HAXM and Creating Android virtual device). Don't know why the message is not more explanatory... This all process should be a lot easier...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an access problem when unzipping the SDK. This can either be a permission problem or (in my case) the default SDK path resolved to a network share.

When going through the setup wizard, it asks if you want to use the Standard or Custom setup. The default option is the Standard one. However, when you use the Custom option, one of the pages is the location of the SDK folder. Verify that you have access to that path or select a different one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the path. Before the installing missing android sdk page, you will see the ***setup wizard - sdk settings*** page. There is a path bottom of the page and it must be change with correct path, like this ;

`C:\Program Files\Android SDK`

and then click the finish button. You will see the downloading necessary files automaticly.

After that you have to create a new project folder

> (name=AndroidStudioProjects),   The folder name must be this name, it's so important.

in your users folder. for example;

C:\Users\'your computer name'\AndroidStudioProjects

It's tried and confirmed by myself. It may be my first solution but I'm using right now.

Answer (score 0):

For OSX users - just reinstall Android Studio and everything will work ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just run Android studio as administrator solve the issue